# Unable to resolve response.text() in promise

Tags: javascript, fetch-api

I am trying to fetch the HTML script of multiple websites using their URLs and send them to a function one by one, for further processing. Here is my code:

```
var responses = [];

for(const [key,value] of Object.entries(links)){
   let resp = fetch('https://api.codetabs.com/v1/proxy?quest='+value)
   responses.push(resp);
}  
                                    
Promise.all(responses)
  .then( htmlfiles =>{
     htmlfiles.forEach(file=>{
       file.text().then(function(data){
          processhtmldata(data); //calling function here
       })
    })
})
```

When I execute the code, I keep getting this error:

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to execute 'text' on 'Response': 
body stream already read
```

What does this error mean? How do I fix this?

Comment: Build the promises so they include getting the text: `const promises = Object.values(links).map(value => fetch('https://api.codetabs.com/v1/proxy?quest=' + value)).then(r => r.text());` then do `Promise.all(promises).then(htmlStrings => htmlStrings.forEach(processhtmldata));`

Comment: It throws this error `Object.values(...).map(...).then is not a function`

Comment: Misplaced a bracket: `const promises = Object.values(links).map(value => fetch('https://api.codetabs.com/v1/proxy?quest=' + value).then(r => r.text()));`